# (Windows) how to launch event viewer GUI console when dealing with huge log files?

Tags: windows, active-directory, eventviewer

i'm having problems working with the event viewer console in windows.

windows version is Windows Server 2019.

the purpose of this server is providing windows event logs gathering from the information system.
the logs are filtered then parsed to a SIEM.

As a consequence this server has to deal with bigger logs file than you would usually find on a classic windows install.

the log file size limit had to be increased on multiple logfiles. the limit on each log file is around 25GB

a standard size limit would be around 20MB.

this is necessary for maintenance purpose. if we have to shut the connection between the SIEM and the windows event collector. as an example the WEC would act as a buffer while the siem is rebooting
or if we have a downtime of multiple minutes.

Now the problem is : When we open the event viewer console on the server. the program is trying to load some stuff in RAM. but loading is taking a long time due to the size of the logfiles.
and ultimately the server reach 100% Ram and is not working properly at this point.

the event viewer won't open properly due to the size of the log files

what can i do to be able to use the event viewer console normally ?

can i tweak the event viewer console so it won't try to load too much stuff when i launch it ? (in some settings or registry ?) cause at the end of day i'm not here to see logs. i just want to manage the subscriptions.
we could reduce the size of the logfiles but we would like to avoid that.

All i want to do right now is configuring the subscription

"But, you could do it in the CLI !"

yes some stuff can be managed throught `wecutil` in powershell and i would aswell want to use it. In fact for some settings i am already using it.
But if i want to manage source initiated subcription computers. which involve selecting computer AD groups. looks like i can't do it with CLI. (if you have a method, i want to hear it !)

Hope somebody can help :)

Comment: You haven't provided the details, but this is usually due to inferior hardware performance. I've worked with logs much larger than this.

Comment: you are right. VM is running fine with only 4GB of ram. As a temporary measure, i wanted to upgrade the RAM just so i would open the event viewer, change some settings. closing event viewer and downgrade RAM. and in fact 16GB of RAM was not enough.

i dont know what amount of RAM would be needed, i chose 16GB randomly. but i can't ask our infrastructure manager 128GB of RAM just so i could open the event viewer.

Comment: But i'm curious on how you managed to open it with large files. maybe my server has an issue. wrong setting, bad version, ....

Comment: These files aren't intended to be used interactively anyway. They are typically forwarder sinks, and need to be large to ensure the files don't overwrite before they can be processed for collection. Additionally, the current hardware is not even close to the *minimum* requirements, which are also too low. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/admin-development/configure-eventlog-forwarding-performance

Comment: Oh, and one other no-no is configuring endpoints subscriptions to use  rendered text. That's basically like saying we don't care about performance or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended being able to use `wecutil` to apply the changes i wanted to do to subscriptions.

i wanted to apply the change at the allowed source computers level.

i needed to change from a built-in computer AD group to a computer security group of my own creation.

to do so i needed to recover the SID of the group with this command :

```
Get-WMIObject win32_group -filter "name='computergroup'"|select Name,sid
```

then i edited the subscription with that piece of information.

```
wecutil ss subname /adc:"[SDDL string + SID]"
```

Again i'm fine with the event viewer being broken on a WEC server as long as i can do anything with `wecutil` and `wevtutil`

Answer (score 1):

You should set the option to auto archive the log file, so the log file that eventviewer open is not too big.

I do that in environment that I manage that are HIPAA to log all login (success or error) from everywhere for some years.

The archived log files are still browsable by the way, and you will be able to store them to a non system-drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. that might be a workable solution.

2 things. 

i would need to configure the client which send the log to the siem to look in to those archive files (that's doable)

and i would need to write a script so the archive won't grow indifinitly.

Comment: there is a bit of a challenge because the SIEM client might need fixed filename to look in to them and not a filename with time added.

+ the SIEM client would try 2 times to send the log. one time when in the default file and one time when the log is archived. that wont create multiple entried in the siem because this log duplication is adressed already. but it would create some more work for the log server + the siem because it will need at least to look the log entry before trashing it if its a duplicate event. but if i don't find an other solution that's the one i will take. thank you

Comment: @Gorshok Did you tried to use archive ? as the way it work is when the file become X size it restart from stractch the file. The archived file got a timestamp and get saved in the same folder, or somewhere else, but it'S no longer viewable directly in eventviewer, you need to open them by hand.